# asp mvc core url localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-routing, asp.net-core-localization

I am trying to localize my app's URLs. Unfortunately, most of the pages show me examples of app localization Like :

> http://localhost/en-US/Home/Index

This is not what I want. I would to localize the URLs like that:

> http://localhost/Welcome
>
> http://localhost/Bienvenue   [ welcome word in French ]

The culture has aleady been managed on my side with a cookie and working well with "CookieRequestCultureProvider" class.

So I have this information and localization in pages are OK.

I succeeded to register all the routes I need. Both of example above working and display the page. Thanks to this :

```
        public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
        {
            foreach (var controller in application.Controllers)
            {
                foreach (var action in controller.Actions)
                {
                    var localizedRouteAttributes = action.Attributes.OfType<LocalizedRouteAttribute>().ToArray();
                    if (localizedRouteAttributes.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var localizedRouteAttribute in localizedRouteAttributes)
                        {
                            var localizedVersions = GetLocalizedVersionsForARoute(localizedRouteAttribute.Name); // GetLocalizedVersionsForARoute contains all routes translated and group by culture.
                            foreach (var localizedVersion in localizedVersions)
                            {
                                if (!action.Selectors.Any(s => s.AttributeRouteModel.Template == localizedVersion.Template))
                                    action.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel(action.Selectors.First()) { AttributeRouteModel = localizedVersion });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So mvc take the last route register in Selectors (if FR, it take FR route).
I can't manage the other routes by this piece of code because it's load with the app. And can't work with a dynamic use (The app permit to change the lang when I want).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example project works: https://github.com/tomasjurasek/AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.Localization

Once it's set up, you can tag routes with

```
[LocalizedRoute("culture", "RouteName")]
```

Do that for each culture you want a unique name for, and the dynamic route it creates will translate to the proper action and execute it. It's also got a tag helper for creating translated links, though if you want to use Url.Action or Html.ActionLink, I find you have to create extension methods that take the culture into account to get them to work fully.

In your case wanting them at the route level instead of /culture/Controller/Action may take some more work, but it might be a useful starting place for you.

Answer (score -3):

look in this little example I hope to help you :)

1) in  your controller :

```
[RoutePrefix("/")]
public HomeController : Controller {


    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Welcome")]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View(); 
    }
}
```

And enable it in route table  " routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); "  like this

```
public class RouteConfig {

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //enable attribute routing
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //convention-based routes
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
    }
}
```

I suggest reading this article from this URL:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

if you have any other question you can ask me

Comment: Thanks for you're answer. :)
But it is not what I want.
I already used the RouteAttribute. But the idea is to get several url for the same route. Like :
>    http://localhost/Welcome
>    http://localhost/Bienvenue
For example.